# Abundance data and GLM

Tags: r, hyperlink, glm

I struggle with running a GLM with abundance data (continuous, zero to 24) in R. I've tried various error structures (Poisson, Gamma) with appropriate links (log, inverse), but it seems to never work. I receive many warnings, but the GLM goes through. I see a number of significant correlations, but for a backward model selection, I need the AIC, which is displayed as "inf" in all cases. What do I mean? Regardless of whether I include one or five explanatory variables (most of them are continuous, one of them is categorial), I do not get an AIC needed for model selection. Can anybody help?

The code looks like this:

```
m_Cyc<-glm(data=Cyc,Abundance_ind_m3~
                Year+Season+MEI+MEI.1+MEI.2+NPGO+NPGO.1+NPGO.2+Distance_land_km+
                Bottom_depth_m,family=Gamma(link="inverse"))
summary(m_Cyc)
```

The warning that I receive is the following:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values.
In addition: Warning message: In log(ifelse(y == 0, 1, y/mu)) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: A Poisson GLM is for count data which is assumed to be integer. If you have non-integer data, you can use Gamma but you can't use Poisson.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor, that is right. Poisson did not work because of the continuous response variable. However, Gamma distribution (inverse link) did not work either and returned the same warning and no AIC. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Please show code and message for the Gamma link. Also please differentiate between Errors and Warnings. An Error means that there was a problem that could not be overcome, they code could not be executed. A Warning means that the could made it through, but things seemed strange and you should check things out to make sure it's okay.

Comment: It would also help to know more about your data. How many rows are there? Of the columns you're using in the model, what `class` are they? Is your response non-negative (I hope so If you're using a log link). If you have categorical variables, roughly how many observations do you have per level? You also say you receive "many warnings", but you've only shown one --- what other warnings are there (just for the Gamma case - the Poisson is clearly a mismatch between model and data).

Comment: Thank you for making this clear one more time. Using the Gamma structure and inverse link, I actually receive an error and a warning

Comment: Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning message:
In log(ifelse(y == 0, 1, y/mu)) : NaNs produced

Comment: The abundance data are all positive and non-zero. The categorical explanatory variable (i.e. season) has three levels (winter, summer, autumn). Each of the the levels has about 450 observations.

Comment: I agree, the Poisson message/warning reflects a mismatch between dataset and error family. The 50+ warnings for when using the Poisson error structure were all similar just displaying different non-integer x values.

Comment: Instead of leaving the clearly wrong code in your question and burying the more relevant stuff down here in comments, please edit your question to make this make more sense. (You can remove the Poisson parts from your question as we've worked that out so they're no longer relevant.)

Comment: Good call, thank you! Do you know why the Gamma family + inverse link return these error and warning?